# CFG and DCFG Decidable problems

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

Can you guys list the problems that you are aware that are **decidable for Context free Language and for Deterministic Context free languages**. I did get some info on list of undecidable problems on Stack Overflow and Wiki, but not related to CFG or DCFG as such in detail. This list of problems (with proofs/links) could be very helpful for people who are looking for such problems.

Answer (score 0):

One of the very interesting Decidable problem related to DCFG and CFG is that. We can compare two DCFG (DPDA) but we cannot Compare two CFG. Equivalence problem for DPDA(DCFG) has been proved to be decidable. [link] (http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/99/ECS-LFCS-99-411/ECS-LFCS-99-411.pdf) Very well explained in this document.